# How to change android studio 3.2.1 theme

Tags: android-studio

I am unable to find a way to change the theme of Android Studio 3.2.1 in Mac OS High Sierra 10.13.6 (17G3025).

[image: Settings of Android Studio]
[image: Android Studio 3.2.1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android Studio -> Preferences ->Editor-> Color scheme 
use Default or Dracula

[image: Screenshot]